# Select Data from Database with Id From URL

Tags: php, mysql

I've a database it is look like this

```
|ID | Name         |  
|081| John Davidson|
```

and i have "index.php" in my website, i've learnt about php form, using method get, and the url is change to index.php?id=081

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<input name="id" value="081"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
```

and when the page is loaded i want to show the name of id 081 from my database, how to do that?

Comment: have you tried any code?

Comment: I've been looking in the web, but i didn't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
//Your index.php file

    if($_GET['id']){
       $id = $_GET['id'];
       $sql="SELECT * FROM tableName where id='$id'";
       $data = mysql_query($sql);
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
       echo $row['name'];

    }
    <form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input name="id" value="081"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form>
```

Answer (score -1):

After submitting , you are sending the id value with GET to index.php by url.
You can catch it with $_GET['id'],and store it in database like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table SET id='".$_GET['id']."'";
$query=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
```

If you want to retrieve this value from the database,you can do it like this:

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM table";
$query=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['id'];
```

**UPDATE** As Abhik mentioned, those statements are very vulnerable, you should probably learn about using prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Another simple way of avoiding sql injection , since it's pretty obvious you are new to php , is to use POST method instead of GET , and check on user input with this little function:

```
function test_input($data){
    $data=htmlentities($data);
    $data=stripslashes($data);
    $data=trim($data);
    return $data;
}

$id=test_input($_POST['id']);
```

Of course,depending on the field type, there must be some validation like min,max length , character allowed , etc.

Comment: Your example is very vulnerable to sql injection and dangerous in real life, why not replace the example with prepared statement.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty , because the OP question was pretty clear.He is probably new to php/database , so i'll just stick to the basics.